# Using htaccess to redirect a directory, but not the files in it

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

On my website, I've got a directory /folder with some images and html in it. I want to redirect users who try to access http://domain.com/folder to http://domain.com/ but don't want requests for the files in that directory to redirect to http://domain.com/ either. When I try

```
Redirect /folder http://domain.com/
```

it breaks the site because now it thinks all the images, etc are in the root directory when it is not. How do i fix this?

Comment: And why would you do that? To prevent users from seeing the content (using mod_autoindex) for that folder? Because if that's the case, then you could just as well turn off indexing on it (using `Options -Indexes`, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options for more info)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`RedirectMatch`](http://php.net/http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead:

```
RedirectMatch ^/folder$ http://example.com/
```

Now the URI path must exactly match `/folder`.