# Joomla - Restricting Access to a Menu Item without making its Items unaccessable

Tags: joomla

How should I deny access to a menu item, but still keep its items accessable? For example, I want to deny access to **www.mysite.com/dir/** , but have the **www.mysite.com/dir/page.html** accessable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298255/using-htaccess-to-redirect-a-directory-but-not-the-files-in-it), and it is to redirect the menu item link using htaccess. Consider to perform both of the below redirections.

```
Redirect ^/dir.html$ http://mysite.com/
RedirectMatch ^/dir$ http://mysite.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla backend, open the selected menu item you wish to change in the Menu Manager, then on the left hand side, you can set the permissions to either **Registered** or **Special**

Comment: But this way the content (i.e. my k2 items) will also be unaccessable.

Comment: Maybe I should create a redirect rule in .htaccess?