# Why does this 301 redirect results in redirect to wrong url?

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, url-rewriting

After relaunching our website, we have to redirect most links to, most of them, entirely new url paths. This has lead us to a list of 301 redirects in htaccess as posted below. For some strange reason though, some rules redirect to a different page than as written in the .htaccess. I have searched the file for any other redirect to that resulting URL (which ends up in a 404, obviously) but it is not formulated.

As an example, the following 301 redirect ends up at the wrong url

```
Removed due to SEO
```

This ends up at: Removed due to SEO

Below the full .htaccess:

```
Removed due to SEO

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Update:

I think it has something to do with the following setup:

removed due to SEO

Because in the first line 'curriculum-vitae-startpagina' is changed to the new structure, it automatically redirects the scond url before the second rewrite can even locate the link. A solution for this would be to write that only the **exact** url '/curriculum-vitae-startpagina/' **without** its childpages would be affected by this rewrite.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I have tried a find and replace within phpmyadmin, but no luck with that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long digging I found the solution myself.

As I already updated in my post, the parent folder redirection was already affecting the child URL's, making the child URL's no longer match the rewrite rule.

To make sure the parent folder rewrite does not affect the child pages/files, use RedirectMatch instead of Redirect:

```
RedirectMatch ^/folder$ http://example.com/
```

This will make sure only the folder itself is rewritten, not its child pages/files.

Solution to the source of this problem was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298255/using-htaccess-to-redirect-a-directory-but-not-the-files-in-it)